# Selecting specific line on richtextbox

Tags: c#

How would I make it so that when a user types in '{' into a richtextbox it will select the next line for them ? For example,

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("{"))
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "    "); // line 1
            // Put user on line 1
            richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "}"); // line 2
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want insert text in between curly braces in a new line, right? ex.. {Hello {world} } should be displayed as two lines hello and world?

Comment: Wouldn't it be good if you handle the key press event instead ?. Basically try to get the process done only if the current key pressed is "{". Right now the code looks for entire text in richTextBox1 so any text after first curly brace would repeat multiple times. It's perfectly fine if that is what you want to achieve but just wanted to mention.

Comment: @EmmanuelPonnudurai  Yeah, I realised that and fixed it accordingly, thanks though :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by getting the length of the text box before adding the second line, and then selecting 0 characters at the end of it after adding the second line.

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("{"))
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "    "); // line 1
        int lastIndex = richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1;
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "}"); // line 2
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = lastIndex;
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}
```